# Do there already exists solutions to quantum gravity which are mathematically consistent and consistent with PRESENT observations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity, black-holes, quantum-information, quantum-gravity

This question is inspired by a [recent video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DHR-ggwafO8) by Sabine Hossenfelder on the topic of black hole information loss. At about 8:23 the makes the claim that "...there are many possible solutions to the problem [of black hole information loss] which are mathematically correct..."

Paraphrasing here: she goes on to criticize that while these solutions might be me mathematically correct, they are at present not able to be verified experimentally and that we won't be able to verify them experimentally for technological reasons for a very long time.

This question is NOT about the experimental verifiability of any quantum gravity theories or solutions to the black information paradox.

Specifically my question is: Are there existing theories of quantum gravity and/or the black hole information paradox* which are mathematically consistent AND consistent with all of our existing relevant experimental observations (including experiments we have testing quantum theories should as particle colliders, quantum optics, quantum information etc. as well as astronomical observations on gravity, gravitational waves, black holes, etc.)?

What I expect in an answer: Again, I fully understand the experimental verification of any quantum gravity theory is very far away technologically. I am not interested AT ALL in PRACTICAL experimental testability of any theory**. If the answer to my question is "Yes, there do exist one or more theories of quantum gravity/black hole information paradox that are (1) mathematically consistent and (2) consistent with all existing quantum and gravitational observations" then I would appreciate a listing of those theories and perhaps some exposition about them including their strengths and weaknesses as mathematical/physical theories. Exposition about strengths and weaknesses in terms of practical experimental verifiability is welcome but given a lower priority in this question.

If there are well-known or commonly-touted quantum gravity theories which are untestable IN PRINCIPLE this information would be of interest to me as well, along with an explanation of why the theory is untestable in principle (and also why it is advertised as a physical theory if it is untestable in principle).

*I list these two topics seperately because I do not know enough about either to know if the answer might be different for one versus the other, or if an answer to one is automatically an answer to the other.

**It is important that the theory is experimentally testable IN PRINCIPLE by a sufficiently technologically advanced entity, but I'm hard pressed to imagine a mathematically physical theory that wouldn't satisfy this condition.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement can be trivially satisfied by taking quantum field theory + general relativity and adding a small modification which cannot be measured at current times. For instance adding a very heavy quantum scalar field, as in scalar tensor theories of gravitation.

Disregarding these trivials solutions and looking at a more unified framework, string theory fits your description as it reproduce gravity and quantum effects. Unfortunately the problem is the opposite here, the theory has so many solutions, including additional fields and effects not present in the standard model, that it is not clear which solution should be selected in the [landscape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory_landscape). This is the main problem that quantum gravity is facing. Reproducing known effects is the easy part.

Comment: thanks for this answer. If string theory is already a sophisticated answer to quantum gravity then I feel I must agree with Hossenfelder's criticism. Why study quantum gravity (other than as a mathematical exercise) until we can do experiments to distinguish between existing theories? Do physics theorists seek non-experimental influences (mathematical elegance, naturalness etc.) upon which to physically prefer one consistent theory over another?

Comment: It's only by studying the theory that we can come up with ideas for experimental verification. Scenarios which we may be able to probe right now include: high energy particle collision, gravitationa waves, cosmic microwave background, gamma rays, lensing. The theory will tell us what to look after in those measurements. It just takes time to come up with good ideas.